# Prove that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log k}$ converges to $0$

Tags: analysis

> Prove that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log k}$ converges to $0.$

Okay, seriously, it's like this question is mocking me.  I know it converges to $0$.  I can feel it in my blood.  I even proved it was Cauchy, but then realized that didn't tell me what the limit *was*.  I've been working on this for an hour, so can one of you math geniuses help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Your sum should start at $k=2$ ;)

Comment: Yeah, it should.  I changed it :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, if $a_n\to 0$, then $\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \to 0$ too.

(For any $\varepsilon>0$, find an $N$ such that $|a_n|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n>N$, and then take enough terms beyond $N$ that they dominate whatever the terms *before* $N$ contribute to the average).

Even more generally (and as an easy consequence), whenever $a_n$ converges, $\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 4):

Stolz Cezaro:

$$\lim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{log k} = \lim \frac{1}{ \log (n+1)}$$

**Edit**
Here is a direct proof:

$$0 \leq  \frac{\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{log k}}{n}  = \frac{\sum_{k=2}^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{log k}}{n}
+ \lim \frac{\sum_{k=\sqrt{n}}^n \frac{1}{log k}}{n} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{log 2}}{n}
+ \frac{(n-\sqrt{n})\frac{1}{\log \sqrt{n}}}{n} $$

Now each of the last two sequences converge to $0$, so squeeze it.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithm to any base is equal to a constant times logarithm to the base $2$. So let's work with base $2$.  For convenience, write $\log n$ for $\log_2 n$.

We use a mild variant of the usual proof that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Note that $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ are both $\ge 1$; $\log 4$, $\log 5$, $\log 6$, and $\log 7$ are all $\ge 2$; $\log 8$, $\log 9$, and so on up to $\log 15$ are all $\ge 3$, and so on. So we have:
$$\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{\log 3} \le \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}=2.$$
$$\frac{1}{\log 4}+\frac{1}{\log 5}+\frac{1}{\log 6}+\frac{1}{\log 7}\le \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=2.$$

In the same way we can see that for any $m \ge 1$,
$$\frac{1}{\log (2^{m})}+\frac{1}{\log (2^{m}+1)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\log (2^{m+1}-1)}\le 2.$$
We conclude that 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{\log k} <2m,$$
since up to $2^{m+1}-1$ we have $m$ chunks each of which has sum $<2$.

Now suppose that $2^{m} \le n \le 2^{m+1}-1$.
Then 
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log k}\le \sum_{k=2}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{\log k} <2m.$$
Thus 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log k} <\frac{2m}{2^{m}}.$$
Finally, it is well-known that $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m}{2^m}=0$.